# Change IntelliJ IDEA left border background color

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I have IntelliJ IDEA 12 and something weird is happening when I load custom font color themes like SonOfObsidian https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/2097581.

The left border displaying the line numbers is white, it is ugly with the dark UI color theme "Darkcula". So I checked the settings to find a way to change this color and I can't find it anywhere.

Unfortunately I can't post an image showing how it looks (low reputation.)

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You may post a link to the image so that others can edit and embed it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extreme Coders is almost right. But for IntelliJ IDEA 12, JetBrains seems to have renamed the color property (I remember looking for this one myself, for quite a while...).

The color is still found under:

```
  Editor > Colors & Fonts > General
```

The name of the color property you are looking for is **Gutter background**.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those who cannot find the option in recent versions (IntelliJ IDEA 2018 and Android Studio 3), here is the exact path:

```regex
 Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Gutter background
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have IntelliJ Idea 12 installed on my system, but this is how you should change the line number color in version 11.1. This should also work for version 12.

Go to `File`->`Settings`

Under `IDE Settings` expand `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` ->`General`

In the list shown on right scroll to `Line Number`

Now you can change the foreground and background colors of the Line Numbers.

Here is the image shown for reference

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but I was looking for the background border color setting not the line number color, haraldK is right on this.